# como puedo mostrar un elemento html y desaparecer otro cuando renderizo el documento html utilizando express

Tags: javascript, express, webforms

yo uso un

```js
res.render("signin",{err,nombre,email, password})
```

*en otras palabras cuando renderizo cambia de elemento a un formulario que tengo para iniciar sesión y tengo que volver a presionar un boton para volver al formulario de crear session, lo que quiero es que renderize y se quede el formulario en el que se enviaron los datos erroneos*

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. 
Lo ideal es compartir  lo que has intentado hacer. Para manejarte en el sitio  
 lee que tipos de preguntas debo evitar asi evitas que tu pregunta sea eliminada o reportada
preguntas constructivas son por ejemplo aquellas que inspiran respuestas que expliquen el porque y el como
e invitan a compartir experiencias respaldadas con hechos y referencias

Comment: Dices: *cuando renderizo cambia de elemento a un formulario que tengo para iniciar sesión y tengo que volver a presionar un boton para volver al formulario de crear session*, entonces, lo más lógico es que **NO** hagas `res.render` si no quieres que te renderice nuevamente. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: sabes que metodo puedo utilizar para que me muestre los errores sin abandonar la ruta?